# Запрос включения локации телефона

Tags: android

Как сделать так, чтобы когда я включил свое приложение с картой гугл ,если локация телефона отключена, приложение делало запрос разрешения включить локацию телефона?

Answer (score 0):

Найти функцию включения GPS прямо из приложения в свое время мне не удалось найти, потому сделал  так

```
public void askForGPS() {
    LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) activity.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    //если мы получили менеджер и он выключен, то запрашиваем включение
    if (manager != null && !manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        //создаем слушатель нажатий на кнопки в диалоговом окне
        OnClickListener listener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                switch (i){
                    //при нажатии на кнопку подтверждения
                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                        //запускаем окно настроек на странице с GPS в надежде, что пользователь включит GPS
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        activity.startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                        //действия в случае отказа включить GPS
                        break;
                }
            }
        };
        new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
            .setMessage(activity.getString("GPS отключен. Перейти в окно настроек, чтобы включить его?"))
            .setPositiveButton("Да", listener)
            .setOnCancelListener(
                 //если пользователь ткнет мимо диалога, то вызываем то же действие, что и при нажатии кнопки отказа
                new OnCancelListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        listener.onClick(dialog, DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
                    }
                }
            )
            .setNegativeButton("Нет", listener).create()
            .show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Дмитрий у меня проблема activity в коде стал красном

Comment: Intent intent new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                            activity.startActivity(intent);
                            break;

Comment: Вы должны положить в эту переменную вашу активити. Передавайте ее в параметр или замените activity на this, если метод находится в активити